# Importing a data frame from module not working

Tags: python, sqlite, module, package

I'm currently trying to accessing a sqllite database using the following module:

/Data_Engine.py

```
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

def get_df(symbol):
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///trading1.db')
    df=pd.read_sql(symbol, engine)
    df[['Open','High','Low','Close']] = df[['o','h','l','c']].astype(float)
    df=df.drop(['o','h','l','c'],axis=1)
```

This works well and if I run *get_df('btcusdt')* as a .ipynb I get this df:

```
                 T        s             v     n      Open      High       Low  \
0    1641994979999  BTCUSDT  121.78956000  2464  43873.91  43930.76  43850.00   
1    1641995039999  BTCUSDT   96.14347000  2598  43911.49  43987.00  43892.02   
2    1641995099999  BTCUSDT   88.10317000  2269  43964.86  43979.81  43910.97   
3    1641995159999  BTCUSDT  137.55266000  2816  43945.96  43985.74  43850.04   
4    1641995219999  BTCUSDT   97.02949000  1713  43872.94  43873.90  43813.15   
..             ...      ...           ...   ...       ...       ...       ...   
112  1642001699999  BTCUSDT   36.20159000  1230  43604.93  43625.62  43573.07   
113  1642001759999  BTCUSDT   38.14229000  1176  43620.18  43651.48  43590.29   
114  1642001819999  BTCUSDT   27.89616000  1224  43650.16  43651.28  43580.00   
115  1642001879999  BTCUSDT   61.17713000  1652  43582.47  43608.94  43541.02   
116  1642001939999  BTCUSDT   37.12097000  1258  43592.42  43600.00  43546.14   

        Close  
0    43911.50  
1    43964.86  
2    43945.96  
3    43872.94  
4    43835.04  
..        ...  
112  43620.17  
113  43650.17  
114  43582.47  
115  43592.42  
116  43556.02  

[117 rows x 8 columns]
```

However when i run the Data_Engine as a .py on a .ipynp file in the same directory (i.e. /Strategy.ipynb) I cannot access df anymore:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import Data_Engine

Data_Engine.get_df('btcusdt')
df


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d91087f9ac88> in <module>
      1 Data_Engine.get_df('btcusdt')
----> 2 df

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

How can I have df available in /Strategy.ipynb?

Comment: `df` is a local variable to the function, which doesn't appear to return anything or put anything in the `global` namespace. You should need to `return df` in your function, and then assign `df=Data_Engine.get_df('btcusdt')` in order to access it at all

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could understand the issue and solve it!